# Acess methods for struct initialisation

Tags: julia

I would like to do something like this:

```
Base.@kwdef mutable struct Setup
    # physics
    lx   = 20.0
    dc   = 1.0
    n    = 4
    # inital condition
    ic(x) = exp(-(x-lx/4)^2)
    # numerics
    nx   = 200
    nvis = 50
    # derived numerics
    dx   = lx/nx
    dt   = dx^2/dc/10
    nt   = nx^2 ÷ 5
    # arrays
    xc   = LinRange(dx/2,lx-dx/2,nx)
    C0 = ic.(xc)
    C = copy(C)
    q = zeros(nx-1)
    # collections for easy use
    dgl_params=[dc,n]
end
```

The problem here is that it says `ic` was undefined. Makes sense, because `ic` is not in the global scope.
Then I tried writing an outside constructor instead (I am not writing an inside constructor as that would overwrite the default constructor).

```
Base.@kwdef mutable struct Setup
    # physics
    lx   = 20.0
    dc   = 1.0
    n    = 4
    # inital condition
    ic(x) = exp(-(x-lx/4)^2)
    # numerics
    nx   = 200
    nvis = 50
    # derived numerics
    dx   = lx/nx
    dt   = dx^2/dc/10
    nt   = nx^2 ÷ 5
    # arrays
    xc   = LinRange(dx/2,lx-dx/2,nx)
    # C0 = ic.(xc)
    C0
    C = copy(C)
    q = zeros(nx-1)
    # collections for easy use
    dgl_params=[dc,n]
end

function Setup()
    Setup(Setup.ic(Setup.xc))
end
Setup()
```

But now it says `DataType has no field ic` which of course makes sense, I want the `ic` of the object itself. However there appears to be no `self`or `this` keyword in julia.
Strangely enough the above seems to work fine with `dx` or `dt` which are also depending on other variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Normally the design is to have multiple dispatch and functions outside of the object
2. When creating `struct`s *always* provide the datatype of elements
3. For this large structs usually you will find out that `using Parameters` package will be more convenient when later debugging
4. The easiest way to circumvent the limitation is to have a lambda function in a field such as (this is however not the recommended Julia style):

```
@with_kw mutable struct Setup
       lx::Float64 = 20.0
       ic::Function = x -> lx * x
end
```

This can be now used as:

```
julia> s = Setup(lx=30)
Setup
  lx: Float64 30.0
  ic: #10 (function of type var"#10#14"{Int64})


julia> s.ic(10)
300
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it is not in the design to have what in Java or C++ you would call "member functions". Part of this is Julia's will to benefit from the [multiple dispatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch) programming paradigm. In Julia, mutables are pointers, so you pass them directly to a function, e.g.

```
function ic(setup::Setup, x)
    return exp(-(x-setup.lx/4)^2)
end
```

That said, there is still a way to have more Java-esque classes, though not super recommended. Check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39133424/how-to-create-a-single-dispatch-object-oriented-class-in-julia-that-behaves-l/39150509#39150509) and, particularly, the answered marked as solution, given by one of Julia's authors themself.

Comment: How is `ic` then applied to C ?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I found the solution.
This does not work, because there are no methods in julia:

```
Base.@kwdef mutable struct S
    n = 5
    m
    f(x) = x + 100
    A = f.(randn(n,m))
end

s = S(m=5) # ERROR: UndefVarError: f not defined
s.A
s.f(5)
```

But this does work, because here `f` is a variable and not a function

```
Base.@kwdef mutable struct S
    n = 5
    m
    f= x-> x + 100
    A = f.(randn(n,m))
end

s = S(m=5)
s.A
s.f(5)
```